# How to add 1 line in the midde between 2 div and adjust the checkbox well in the div?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem to add 1 line in the midde between 2 div and adjust align the checkbox well in the div. Below is my coding:

```html
<style>
  .div1,
  .div2 {
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Printing</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Matt/Gloss Lam</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Plate</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Spot UV</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Paper</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> UV</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Folding</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Machine Varnish</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Perfect/ Lock Bind</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Matt/Gloss</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Staple Bind</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Diecut</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Threat Sewing</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Creasing Line</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Wire - 0</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Gluing</strong></input>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div2 pull-right">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Remark/Instruction:<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;*</span></label><br><br>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="promotion_description" name="promotion_description" title="" style="margin: 0px -24px 0px 0px; width: 100%; height: 93px;"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The output show me like below the picture:

[Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Jl8.png)

Actually I want the output like below the sample picture:

[Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTtVR.png)

Hope anyone can guide me solve these problems. Thanks.

Comment: are you using `bootstrap.css`?

Comment: You should _start_ by modifing the HTML here. Using `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>` to create spacing, is not a good idea to begin with. And all those texts that you put into `strong` right now, really, really, _really_ want to be `label` instead.

Comment: The  input `> <strong>stuff</strong></input>` should be `/> <label class="bold-me">stuff</label>` or some such class to do the "strong" as bold (or put the strong inside the label element

Comment: An `id` MUST be unique within the document making this markup invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add CSS as below:

```css
.div1{
    margin-right: 25px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}
strong {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Thanks!

Comment: This would be a much better answer if the HTML from the question was also inside your snippet to illustrate the solution

Answer (score 1):

[image: CSS- Boot Strap]U Can Try This:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
  .div1,
  .div2 {
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong>
            Printing</strong></input><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Matt/Gloss
            Lam</strong></input><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong>
            Plate</strong></input><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Spot
            UV</strong></input><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong>
            Paper</strong></input><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong>
            UV</strong></input><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong>
            Folding</strong></input><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Machine
            Varnish</strong></input><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Perfect/ Lock
            Bind</strong></input><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong>
            Matt/Gloss</strong></input><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Staple
            Bind</strong></input><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong>
            Diecut</strong></input><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Threat
            Sewing</strong></input><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Creasing
            Line</strong></input><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Wire -
            0</strong></input><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong>
            Gluing</strong></input><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <label class="control-label">Remark/Instruction:<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;*</span></label><br><br>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="promotion_description" name="promotion_description" title="" style="margin: 0px -24px 0px 0px; width: 100%; height: 93px;"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if the this was in a snippet

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```css
.container {
  display: flex; 
}

.leftContainer {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 2px Solid #000;
}

.inputContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.rightContainer {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftContainer">
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Printing</strong></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Matt/Gloss Lam</strong></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Plate</strong></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Spot UV</strong></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Paper</strong></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> UV</strong></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Folding</strong></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Machine Varnish</strong></input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Perfect/ Lock Bind </strong></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Matt/Gloss</strong></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Staple Bind</strong></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Diecut</strong></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Threat Sewing</strong></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Creasing Line</strong></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option" value="1"><strong> Wire - 0</strong></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="point_option" id="point_option" value="1"><strong> Gluing</strong></input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rightContainer">
    <div>
      <label>Remark/Instruction:<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;*</span></label><br><br>
      <div>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="promotion_description" name="promotion_description" title="" style="margin: 0px -24px 0px 0px; width: 100%; height: 93px;"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution without `bootstrap.css`

Answer (score 1):

**How about this! Try it you will get the desired result.**

```css
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
  
      .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        padding: 20px 0;
      }
  
      .div1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 20%;
        border-right: 1px solid #000;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
        padding: 0 15px;
      }
  
      .div1 .chks {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 50%;
      }
  
      .div1 label {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 0;
      }
  
      .div2 {
        flex: 1 0 auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding: 0 15px;
        align-items: center;
      }
  
      .div2 .form-group {
        width: 40%;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="div1">
        <div class="chks">
          <label for="rm_option-1"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-1" value="1">Printing</label>
          <label for="rm_option-2"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-2" value="1">Plate</label>
          <label for="rm_option-3"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-3" value="1">Paper</label>
          <label for="rm_option-4"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-4" value="1">Folding</label>
          <label for="rm_option-5"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-5" value="1">Perfect/ Lock
            Bind</label>
          <label for="rm_option-6"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-6" value="1">Staple
            Bind</label>
          <label for="rm_option-7"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-7" value="1">Threat
            Sewing</label>
          <label for="rm_option-8"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-8" value="1">Wire - 0</label>
        </div>
        <div class="chks">
          <label for="rm_option-9"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-9" value="1">Matt/Gloss
            Lam</label>
          <label for="rm_option-10"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-10" value="1">Spot UV</label>
          <label for="rm_option-11"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-11" value="1">UV</label>
          <label for="rm_option-12"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-12" value="1">Machine
            Varnish</label>
          <label for="rm_option-13"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-13" value="1">Matt/Gloss</label>
          <label for="rm_option-14"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-14" value="1">Diecut</label>
          <label for="rm_option-15"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-15" value="1">Creasing
            Line</label>
          <label for="rm_option-16"><input type="checkbox" name="rm_option" id="rm_option-16" value="1">Gluing</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="div2">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
          <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Remark/Instruction:<span style="color:red;">&nbsp;*</span></label><br><br>
          <div class="col-lg-7">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="promotion_description" name="promotion_description" title=""
              style="margin: 0px -24px 0px 0px; width: 100%; height: 93px;"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```